# How to create a new llvm BasicBlock and insert after the other Block?

Tags: llvm

I am writing some codes to insert some Instructions in a llvm BasicBlock，and I need to create a new BasicBlock to insert after a block，I have tried

```
LLVM::BasicBlock b=LLVM::BasicBlock()
```

But I don't know what parameters should be written inLLVM::BasicBlock，and I don't
know how to name the BasicBlock

So could you help me to create a new llvm BasicBlock and insert it after the other Block?

Answer (score 4):

In LLVM hierarchy, instructions are associated with a basic block, basic blocks with a function, and functions with a module. To create a basic block,

```
BasicBlock* mainblock = BasicBlock::Create(context, "entrypoint", mainFunction);
```

where `entrypoint` is the name of the block and `mainfunction` is the function containing the block (which you should have already declared of course).

Emitting instructions in LLVM is achieved with an instance of the `IRBuilder<>` class whose constructor takes an `llvm::LLVMContext` instance. i.e

```
llvm::LLVMContext context;
IRBuilder<> builder(context);
```

This builder instance is like your pen for emitting LLVM IR. To place the tip of the pen on a particular page i.e specify in which basic block it emits, just call

```
builder.SetInsertPoint(mainblock);
```

Where `mainblock` is the basic block we want to write to. Henceforth all calls to `builder` will emit instructions in this block.

Comment: Thank you very much.But I still can not understand, how can I create a Funtion(like "mainFunction" ) For example,I want create a empty function like "void mainFunction(){}"

Comment: First create the function type which defines the function return type and the type of each of its arguments i.e `llvm::FunctionType *mainFunctionType = llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getVoidTy(), false);`  in your case with no arguments. Then do `llvm::Function* mainFunction = llvm::Function::Create(mainFunctionType, llvm::GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, "mainfunction", module));` which creates the function given the function type, visibility from other modules, function name (which you'll need later for calling the function) and a pointer to the module containing the function,